# How do I ignore errors with volumemounts in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We have a container running with a CIFS share as volumeMount:

```
 volumeMounts:
 - name: test
   mountPath: /mnt/test/lt145

 - name: test
   hostPath:
     path: /mnt/test/lt145
```

lt145 stands for laptop 145.

Now I wanted to rollout a new version of the container but the laptop was turned off so the share could not be found.

"failed to stat /mnt/test/lt145 host is down"

Now the container wont start!

Is there a way to say that this error should be ignored or only mount if available? Like with configmaps and secrets the "optional: true" setting.
It's not critical so the container should start when the laptop is down.